# Django queryset order by latest value in related field

Tags: python, django

Consider the following Models in Django:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Item_Price(models.Model):
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
  item = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name = 'prices')
  price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 15)
```

The price of an item can vary throughout time so I want to keep a price history.

My goal is to have a single query using the Django ORM to get a list of Items with their latest prices and sort the results by this price in ascending order.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It might be better to use [**`django-simple-history`**](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) this will construct an extra table for historical records which makes querying for the "current" state easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Subquery` to obtain the latest `Item_Price` object and sort on these:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

last_price = Item_Price.objects.filter(
    item_id=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-created_on').values('price')[:1]

Item.objects.annotate(
    last_price=Subquery(last_price)
).order_by('last_price')
```

For each `Item`, we thus obtain the latest `Item_Price` and use this in the annotation.

That being said, the above modelling is perhaps not ideal, since it will require a lot of complex queries. [**`django-simple-history`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does this differently by creating an extra model and save historical records. It also has a manager that allows one to query for historical states. This perhaps makes working with historical dat simpeler.

Answer (score 0):

You could prefetch them in order to do the nested ordering inline like the following:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

prefetched_prices = Prefetch("prices", queryset=Item_Price.objects.order_by("price"))

for i in Item.objects.prefetch_related(prefetched_prices): i.name, i.prices.all()
```